# How to override a field to 'null' in spring yml file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I have a yml file with the following content.

```
FirstQueueType: &QueueType1
    prop1: true
SecondQueueType: &QueueType2
    prop1: false

BaseQueue: &BaseQueue
    name: abc
    type:
       <<: *QueueType1

CategoryQueue: &CategoryQueue
    <<: *BaseQueue
    type: ~
    name: xyz
```

When I load this file with the following code in spring + java

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    context.register(QueueConfig.class, ...);
    context.refresh();
    QueueConfig configs = context.getBean(QueueConfig.class);
```

I get the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [abc.QueueType] for property 'type': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
```

How can i reset the value of a property in the parent class to null when inheriting (in this case setting 'type' property of CategoryQueue to NULL).

I tried with

- null
- ~